# Open File keeps growing despite emptied content

Tags: sed, filesize

How can I pipe a text stream into a file and, while the file is *still* in use, wipe it for job rotation?

---

Long version:

I've been struggling for a while onto an apparently minor issue, that's making my experiments impossible to continue.

I have a software collecting data continuously from external hardware (radiotelescope project) and storing in a csv format. Being the installation at a remote location I would, once a day, copy the saved data in a secure place and wipe the file content while, for the same reason, I can NOT to stop the hardware/software, thus software such as log rotation wouldn't be an option.

For as much effort spent [see my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013256/truncate-open-file-doesnt-affect-size), it seems the wiped file keeps growing although empty.

Bizarre behavior, showing file size, truncate file, show file size again:

```
pi@tower /media/data $ ls -la radio.csv ;ls -s radio.csv;truncate radio.csv -s 1; ls -la radio.csv ;ls -s radio.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 994277 Jan 18 21:32 radio.csv
252 radio.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1 Jan 18 21:32 radio.csv
0 radio.csv
```

Then, as soon as more data comes in:

```
pi@tower /media/data $ ls -la radio.csv ;ls -s radio.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1011130 Jan 18 21:32 radio.csv
24 radio.csv
```

I thought to pipe the output into a sed command and save right away, with no luck altogether. Also, filesystem/hardware doesn't seems buggy (tried different hardware/distro/filesystem).

Would anyone be so nice to give me a hint how to proceed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, try to include all relevant information in your question. Many readers won't bother following links to other questions for context.

Comment: I am guessing the data gathering software *holds the file open* continuously, rather than closing it and then re-opening it for append on the next pass. Try renaming the file, and seeing if the software continues writing to it under the new name - I guess it will if it is holding it open - but if it doesn't then that could be a solution. The other question is how you are truncating the file - it doesn't seem to go to zero bytes. Try truncating with simply `> radio.csv` or `cat /dev/null > radio.csv`.

Comment: Darn, it's right! Renaming the file makes the stream keep going to the new one. Tried cat /dev/null > radio.csv with no success, file keeps growing after having been emptied [edited: I mean keeps growing from original size although was zeroed a second before].Uhm... now what? Any suggestion?

Comment: @Michele: What about creating a new file say **newfile** and then moving this newfile to the file in question by `mv newfile radio.csv`. You could even force it by using `mv -f newfile radio.csv` which will forcibly replace the old file. Once you find that this step is successful you could automate the whole process of storing and deleting the data by writing a bash script.

Comment: thank you sjsam for the effort and sorry for taking so long to answer. Actually, what you said is technically correct - and in a matter of fact I tried every flavor of this approach... unsuccessful. It seemed, in the end, a faulty software keeping file open. In other words, **no matter** how I was trying to truncate the file, software was keep writing at the end of **previous** one, despite the drop. Spent long hours on the issue, apparently the only working solution remain the tee option as written on top (solved) issue.Of course, I then automated the whole process, but that's another story:)

Comment: You should write about the solution in the answer box provided, and then accept that answer. This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Piped into `tee` with `-a` option. The file was kept open by originating source.

Option APPEND of `tee` helped to stick at the EOF new data; in the given issue, appending to the beginning when file zeroed.

For search engine and future reference:

```
sudo rtl_power -f 88M:108M:10k -g 1 - | tee -a radio.csv -
```

Now emptying the file with

```
echo -n > radio.csv
```

gets the file zeroed as expected.